# Python GAE app using 2-legged OAuth and 3-legged OAuth at same time

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-apps, 2-legged

I'm coding a Python - Google App Engine application. There are 2 important things this app must do:

- Write in user's calendar.
- Write in user's profile (working with users in a Google Apps domain)

First operation is easy. If I understood OAuth, this is the classical 3-legged scenario. The scenario for which OAuth was originally developed. The logged user provides credentials to the client (my app) to access the user's data (calendar) on his/her behalf. So, this can be done just with the logged user's credentials.

Second operation is not so easy. It can't be done with just the logged user's credentials. This is a 2-legged OAuth scenario. So, I need to delegate in a Google Apps domain admin's account to access the users's profiles using Google Profiles API (via google data library). So far, I hardcode admin user/password in a json file, and my app loads that file. But that sounds kind of *dirty* for me.

At the end, my app needs to handle the classical 3-legged OAuth scenario (no problem, just need the logged user's credentials) plus a 2-legged OAuth scenario (need administrator credentials).

Is there any official or more elegant way to handle both scenarios in Google App Engine, working with Google Apps domain, that hardcoding admin credentials?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no way to authorize a write operation to Google Contacts Data API using 2-legged OAuth.

[Google's documentation specifies which APIs are accessible via 2-legged OAuth](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162105), but it seems that someone at Google's forgot to specify that some of them are read-only :-S

Some people had the same problem [here](http://pilif.github.com/2010/06/google-apps-provisioning-two-legged-oauth/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749841/2-legged-oauth-with-google-api-java-client).

I look forward someone at Google to fix this. Until then, harcoding admin-level credentials is the only option I know that it works. I don't like it at all: it's *dirty* but *effective*. If someone knows a more elegant zen-level way, please illuminate us!

Comment: It was [announced](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) in April of 2012 that OAuth 1.0 (or 2-legged OAuth as you've been referring to it) is being deprecated as is using a traditional password (Client Login), so it is in your best interest to get this working with OAuth 2.0. I'll try to find a helpful solution on this.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. So far, our big problem is that we need admin credentials. So, the OAuth 2.0 credentials we get via oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets, for example, are not valid. Am I right? (client_secrets.json downloaded from Google API console. It's a Client ID for web applications)